# How to get a colored console output while running Behave tests on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I run my Gherkin tests (Behave with Python) on Jenkins. I want to get a colored console output for the tests (Passed steps marked in green, Failed in Yellow, Skipped in blue) for better readability. Kindly advise. TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think the plugin Ansi color should do the job. I use it with cucumber and it works great.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin

Answer (score -1):

This was answered over here: [Behave test runner has no colored output on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718995/behave-test-runner-has-no-colored-output-on-jenkins/33221229#33221229)

You need to install the latest behave 1.2.6-dev0:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/behave/behave
```