# Behave test runner has no colored output on Jenkins

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, ansi-escape

I have setup jenkins on Ubuntu server 14.04 on an EC2 instance. I have some selenium tests that I execute using [`behave`](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) as test runner.

On Jenkins I have also installed the plugin [AnsiColor](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) hoping that I can get color output on the jenkins console, however I get color for everything else except for the Gherking syntax. Selenium errors, python debug, everything has color...**except** for the output of behave.

Now the thing is if I run the tests on a Mac or on Ubuntu but not with the Jenkins user, everything works fine and the colors are there.

I really don't have any code to post, but I can say what I have tried to no avail:

- running behave with `behave --color`
- mapping the color map of AnsiColorPlugin to the escape sequences of behave found in `formatter/ansi_escapes.py`
- adding `#!/bin/bash`to jenkins build script to make sure it does not get executed with `sh`instead of `bash`

If this is of any relevance I am using python 3.4 on `virtualenv`

Besides the actual answer, any suggestions on how to debug this are also welcome! thanks

Comment: which option is enabled right now in AnsiColor plugin (Xterm)? if "behave" output lines echoes/prints a given keyword everytime in each line, you can try "Log parser plugin" and create a parser rule file with using "info" and provide that keyword in the pattern. All the lines will turn BLUE.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: @DTI-Matt No I didn't. Rest assured that if I will find a hack I will post it as an answer, if I will ever try again.

Answer (score 3):

Reading original source code of `PrettyFormatter`, there's no way to force it to use colors as it uses `isatty` to determine if it's writing to actual terminal.

However, necessary modifications to enable color output are trivial:

https://github.com/mrkafk/behave/commit/5fa2dd3fd1dc7149857df4da156d8fd00f5058a5

I've created pull request and tested it to work in Jenkins (after enabling parsing ANSI codes in project configuration of course):

[image]